# How to Change Excel Power Query Paramaters with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

How to change Excel PowerQuery Paramaters with VBA?

i.e. These Paramaters:

[image: Excel Power Query]

Right now the Paramater has a value of 8, and is used in refreshing all other power queries.  How can I change this paramater with VBA?

The Macro recorder does not show anything.

Comment: Do you frequently need to change the parameter?  If so, you could pick up the value from a cell. Otherwise, just change the value in the M code.

Comment: Yes, I need to change it frequently.  The reason the vba code simply copies the workbook an arbitrary number of times (changing the parameter in each one).  The copied workbook is not a macro workbook, which is why I am using Query Parameters.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excelisfun+parameterized+powerquery&oq=excelisfun+parameterized+powerquery&aqs=chrome..69i57.10308j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8    I partic like the ExcelIsFun versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to QHarr, I figured it out.  Simply edit the Power Query M Code - the Parameter value is first item in the Code.

e.g.

```
5 meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type="Number", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]
```

5 is the Parameter Value.

To edit, use the "Formula" Property e.g.

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries([ParameterName]).Formula = 'New code here
```

Comment: How do you run the query?  Do a Refresh?
Can you share more M code so I can see where you added the meta?

Comment: The meta is the first line i.e. for a parameter, the M code I posted above is all there is.  Refresh other queries that depend on the parameter.