# How do I change a Parameter in Power Query without it converting the value to a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, powerquery

I was following the instructions on this thread:

[How to Change Excel Power Query Paramaters with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703993/how-to-change-excel-power-query-paramaters-with-vba)

which lists the following code for changing a Power Query parameter:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries([ParameterName]).Formula = 'New code here
```

However it converts the value into a formula and adds "= " to the front of it:

[image: Error]

I need to update the source of my query because the GUID expires and needs to be refreshed.

```
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("http://api.aceproject.com/?fct=getprojects&guid=" & GUID & "&Filtercompletedproject=False&projecttemplate=0&assignedonly=True")),
```

The only solutions I can find require using a value stored in a cell, but I want to avoid storing the GUID in a cell for security reasons.

Using VBA how can I change either just the parameter value (without it converting into a formula) or the entire source URL?

Comment: "I want to avoid storing the GUID in a cell for security reasons" - if that GUID is in the VBA code, it's not secure. Also that GUID is sent over HTTP as part of a URL, which isn't secure. There is no valid security concern with that GUID, it's already public.

Comment: I get that, but I'm just looking for "more secure" than storing it in plain text in a cell that's easily visible. I have a login script that refreshes the GUID value upon opening the file, which automatically clears when the file is closed. This ensures the next person opening the file doesn't get access to the GUID of the previous user. This isn't the topic of my question though, so will me explaining my reasoning for NOT wanting the GUID stored in a cell help you answer my question, or are you just nitpicking?

Comment: Where are you getting the GUID you need to pass in from?

Comment: I get the GUID from the API via a login function then I store it as a class variable.

I can manipulate the GUID with ease, the issue is feeding it into the Power Query source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was using double quotes to force a text value to the formula:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries("GUID").Formula = """dogs"""
```

Here's the final version, which passes the variable through as text:

```
Sub RefreshQuery_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Queries("GUID").Formula = """" & GUID & """"
End Sub
```

To ensure the query retains the parameter property, add in the following meta data:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Queries("GUID").Formula = """" & GUID & """" & " meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type=""Text"", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]"
```